# Is it possible to route traffic without doing a redirect when hosting a static site?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to serve the file `build/1.coolfile.html` on the url `/1/coolfile`. I can't find a way to "rewrite" the url like that. All that I see are methods to do a [http redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html).

Comment: This question shouldn't be downvoted; it's well-formed, relevant, and interesting.

Comment: @user875234 you have not said so explicitly, but is this a static site hosted on S3?  Are you also using CloudFront?  Is there a consistent pattern to these rewrites?  Is there a reason why you don't just save the files with the names you want to see in the URL?

Comment: Yes, static site on S3. Im not currently using cloudfront but I could be. Yes, there is a consistent pattern, the one above. There is one another pattern but it's similiar. My two main reasons for needing the rewrite are I dont want to have .html in the url and because thats how I was serving the files before I decided to host them on S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael - sqlbot may have been hinting at you can do it with cloudfront and a lambda. Cloudfront is easy to setup but lambda lets you set it up and then doesn't work and you're left with zero clues and have to just try random things for hours on end until it finally works. Have fun.

**Edit** - I'm going to be kind and rewind since this was a traumatic experience.

1. Setup a distribution that points to your S3 bucket. If you already created your S3 bucket be advised that you only need one distribution. Go to route 53 and point your A records at your distribution. Documentation may say to use CNAME. I used A because CNAME didn't work for example.com and www.example.com
2. You don't need a special IAM account to create the lambda. Just do it on your admin account (security people will cry).
3. Create your lambda. Let it create a new role for your lambda to run under. You will need to edit the policy for that role in IAM (go to aws console and type IAM). Mine looks like this (notice I added s3:GetObject)

   ```
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "logs:CreateLogStream",
               "logs:PutLogEvents",
               "logs:CreateLogGroup",
               "s3:GetObject"
           ],
           "Resource": "*"
       }
   ]
   ```

   }
4. create your lambda and publish it. just go with the start code they have. in the top right it will print out the "uri" of the lambda. it looks like this  `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:169014044482:function:RewriteURL:9`
5. Go back to cloudfront > your distribution > behavior > lambda function association > add one for origin request (its not cached and it requested from the bucket) and one for viewer request (its cached and is requested from cloudfront). use the "uri" from above in the text boxes.
6. wait a year for cloudfront to update and go to your site. you if it worked you will see a log for your lambda in cloudwatch under the section for lambda > yourLambdaFunctionName
7. if this doesn't work be advised that you can go directly to the distribution url (looks like this d1tplmeznzg2c3.cloudfront.net). this may be helpful if something in your dns is not right. that way you can at least verify that the lambda is hooked up right and functioning.
8. Once you get all that **** done you can write a lambda that looks similar to this (unless they've changed it since I wrote this ha ha).

   exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
       const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
       request.uri = "/images/favicon.png";
       callback(null, request);
   } // sorry but stackoverflow wont format this code. yes each line is indented by 4 spaces and there are line breaks above and below it LOLLL!!!!

Make sure to log back in to amazon console every single time you open a new tab to access a different service and definitely make sure to have it redirect you to the console regardless of the page that you were on. Don't ask me how to get it to do a redirect. Every solution I have tried doesn't work and I've tried quite a few. ...if you are just getting started with this I would advise against using AWS unless you are willing to dump a ton of time into it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no service from AWS that can re-write URLs for you. You will need to deploy a load balancer such as Apache or nginx to do this, I think you can run apache on Elastic Beanstalk if you don't want to create and manage an infrastructure.